# Rename builtin prototype method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am asked a question today that took me by surprise .  I know `string.repeat(number)` repeat string to the said numbers in javascript. Example.

```
"Father".repeat(3)
```

Should print

> FatherFatherFather

I was asked to do the same thing but instead using `.repeat` , i should use my new method like `strRepeater` in such a way that.

```
"Father".strRepeater(3)
```

Should equal

```
"Father".repeat(3);
```

Please how do i do this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Homework? `Function.prototype.call` will do the job just fine.

Comment: @Knu not home work. Interview actually and couldn't answer. So taken by surprise. Thank you though, would have a look.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 3 options:

1. Creating an alias to the prototype:

   ```
   String.prototype.strRepeater = String.prototype.repeat;
   ```
2. Creating a wrapper around the prototype:

   ```
   String.prototype.strRepeater = function() {
     return this.repeat.apply(this, arguments);
   };
   ```
3. Creating your own method:

   ```
   String.prototype.strRepeater = function(times) {
     var res = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
       res += this;
     }
     return res;
   };
   ```

Comment: It really didn't occurred to me that i can just add a new prototype to the `String` . Was asked in an interview :(

Comment: well, if anything, you'll know for next time :)

Comment: the second option isn't working. Where does arguments comes from pls ?

Comment: Adding `this` parameter fixed it . I think `return this.repeat.apply(arguments);` should be `return this.repeat.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: @NuruSalihu yup, you're right, I forgot to pass the context. Its fixed now.

Comment: `Where does arguments comes from?` - basically it's an array-like object that contains every argument value (e.g. in `foo('bar', 123)`, `arguments` is `{0: 'bar', 1: 123}`) that gets passed to all functions. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Answer (score 7):

While the other answers adding to the prototype are completely correct, they're also a bad habit to get into.

If adding anything to a prototype you should be using `Object.defineProperty()` so it doesn't appear as a member of the method (ie, a `for...in` loop will show up members, but not when added properly).

While this isn't a requirement for the String prototype, it's always a bad idea to get into bad habits and then wonder why things aren't working correctly later...

So the safe way to add the method is:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "strRepeater", {
    value: function(number) {
        return this.repeat(number)
    }
};
```

Or to be even more safe:

```
if (!String.prototype["strRepeater"]) {
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "strRepeater", {
        value: function(number) {
            return this.repeat(number)
        }
    };
}
```

On a technical note, this sets it with the defaults of `enumerator: false`, `configurable: false` and `writeable: false` - which translates to "no, you can't list me, delete me, or change me".

[Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) on MDN.

Comment: 'Good practice' would say you shouldn't even mess with builtins in the first place.

Comment: All depends on what you need to do - but if you don't understand exactly what you're doing then it's definitely safer to leave them alone ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```js
String.prototype.strRepeater = function(number) {
  return this.repeat(number)
};

console.log("Father".strRepeater(3));
```

Explanations:

- `String.prototype.strRepeater` add your function to the String object
- `this.repeat(number)` will call the repeat built-in function with your current string in`this` with number as param
- `return` returns the result of `.repeat()` outside `strRepeater()`